# Can I use ebay commerce api without user sign-in action?

Tags: jquery, flask, ebay-api

As well known, some eBay OAuth Scopes such as "commerce.catalog.readonly" require user access token, not application access token. And once this API is called, the browser will be redirected to sign-in page of eBay.

I am developing eBay search toolkit using flask framework.
I want to summarize this step so that the user doesn't need to pass the sign-in page. How can I do?

I tried to use selenium to type username and password to sign-in page, but it looks not good. I am looking for more effective alternative.